# Convert a string into an alias for an operator in c++

Tags: c++, operators

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically apply a comparison operator to two variables in c++. For example:

I have a list of data such as:

```
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <list>

typedef boost::variant< short, int, long, long long, double, string > flex; 
typedef pair<string, flex> flex_pair;
typedef list< flex_pair > row_entry;

list< row_entry > all_records; // This is the primary list
list< row_entry >::iterator all_records_it; // An iterator to move through the primary list
```

Now, let's say that there is a row in `all_records` that looks like this:

```
all_records[0]["price"] = 220.45;
all_records[0]["time"] = 1336948802;
all_records[0]["name"] = "some item";

all_records[1]["price"] = 180.0;
all_records[1]["time"] = 1336948102;
all_records[1]["name"] = "another item";
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
comparer(all_records[0]['price'], 190, ">");
```

Which would test for `if(all_records[0]['price'] > 190)` and return wether or not that evaluates to true. Similarly, if I were to do:

```
comparer(all_records[0]['price'], 190, "==");
```

It would test for `if(all_records[0]['price'] == 190)` and return whether or not that evaluates to true

I know that I can do this using a bunch of `if`/`else` statements or a `switch` statement, but is there some more elegant way to do this, such as:

```
return val1 cmpr_string val2;
```

Where `val1 = all_records[0]['price']`, `val2 = 190`, and `cmpr_string` is the > comparison operator (converted from the ">" string to the comparison operator. Essentially, I guess I am looking for a way to convert a string into some sort of alias for an operator that can be used just like the original operator. It would be great if I could also use this for operators other than just comparison operators (for example, `+` and `-`).

Please note that I used `boost::variant` for `all_records` because in reality, that's what I will be doing (each value can be of a different type for different members of the list). If it makes it easier, I can put in a system to ensure that pairs with identical keys in different rows of `all_records` have the same type. So, if `all_records[0]['price']` is a `double`, it will be a `double` for all `all_records[n]['price']`

Comment: Check out `<functional>`. It has functors such as `std::less` and `std::greater` built for purposes like this, and like `std::sort (myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), std::greater<T>());`, which as you might guess, sorts an array in descending order. Even if you need the string there, you can map the symbols to the appropriate functors.

Comment: From the answer-to-question-might-not-be-solution-to-problem department:  If you don't your columns at compile time, consider [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org) or another sort of database.  If you do know your columns at compile time, I'd another approach this problem very differently.